# Asymptotic study of complex integrals

Tags: reference-request, complex-analysis

Anyone know a good reference for the asymptotic study  of integrals of the form $\int_{\Gamma}f(s)e^{ng(s)}ds$ , $n\to\infty$, where $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic functions in the domain containing the contour $\Gamma$?. The books I have consulted only refer to the case where $g(z)$ has critical points and  that study reduces to the method of Laplace or Waltson's lemma. But, i need to study the case where $g(z)$ has no critical points.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: "The books I have consulted" - it would be helpful to mention which books, so that we don't waste your time telling you to look at things you've already seen.

Comment: @J.M:These are some of the books I read: "Asymptotic Analysis", "Complex Variables Introduction and Applications Second Edition" , "Applied Mathematics Science: Asymptotic Analysis and Techniques of Asymptotic Analysis", "The Theory of Functions by Titchmarsh"
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Applied Asymptotic Analysis" of Peter Miller ?

Comment: Ok, I'll look to see if I can find. Thank you..